# problem play an mp3 after pushing viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avplayer

in my tableViewController on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

i push my viewController

```
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease] animated:YES];
```

in myViewController i've import AVFoundation and add via IB three buttons for play/pause/stop a song

```
myViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface fotos : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)pause:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender;
```

and i've implement in this way

```
myViewController.m
@implementation fotos
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"peter"                                                          
ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
[filePath release];
[fileURL release];  
}

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender {

if(!player.playing)
{
 [player play];
}
}

-(IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
[player pause];
}

-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
[player stop];
}
```

i've connect my action in IB but when i try to play my file i get

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    
[UIViewController play:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5619e70'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01009be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0115e5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0100b6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f7b366 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f7af22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   UIKit                               0x0041ea6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
6   UIKit                               0x004ad1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
7   UIKit                               0x004af647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
8   UIKit                               0x004ae1f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
9   UIKit                               0x004430d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
10  UIKit                               0x0042437a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
11  UIKit                               0x00429732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
12  GraphicsServices                    0x01b18a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00feb064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00f4b6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f48983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f48240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00f48161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
18  GraphicsServices                    0x01b17268 GSEventRunModal + 217
19  GraphicsServices                    0x01b1732d GSEventRun + 115
20  UIKit                               0x0042d42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
21  Training Cocoa                      0x00001bc4 main + 102
22  Training Cocoa                      0x00001b55 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

i've also try to play in viewDidLoad but nothing.

Any suggestion?
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since player is a property try referencing it by
`[self player]`

so you might have `[[self player] play];`

Comment: thank's, nice reply. i've notice my newbe error, now i create a viewController referencing to myViewController and all works myViewController *myC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNib ....] and pushing myC.